# Index Categories in Expression Engine search results

Tags: categories, search

I have a site that needs to include category names as a parameter for search results that's keywords might be the cat name.

Anyone know of a way to do this, or possibly a plugin that converts a chosen set of categories to field data automatically so I can spoof it.

Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Preparse](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/preparse/) from Solspace. It's a free extension that allows you to run a template against your entries when you save them and store the output in a field.

Low actually talked about this [on his blog](http://gotolow.com/blog/searching-non-field-data-with-low-search) in the context of Low Search, but you can use the same principle for the native search module as well.

I recommend taking a look at the blog post and setting Preparse up on your site. I've done it before, and it works great.

Comment: By the way, since version 2.4, it's possible to [add category info to the search index](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/collections#categories) in Low Search.

Comment: Good point :) I love Low Search, and would highly recommend using that instead of the native search, if you're able to use it. Saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: Thanks Chaps. I'd bought Low Search for another site but hadn't thought about it working in this way. Will have a tinker and buy another license if it fits the bill.